# NOT ABLE TO PASS jwt token from header using golang fiber app.test

Tags: unit-testing, go, httprequest, fibers

can anyone help me im trying to create function unit testing but i cant get pass jwt auhtentication because fiber app.test didnt pass any jwt value from authorization header
i can get data if im using param but i cant use bearer if i use that

my code :

```
app := fiber.New()
urlvalue, _ := url.Parse("/test")
values := urlvalue.Query()
//values.Add("id", strconv.Itoa(2))
urlvalue.RawQuery = values.Encode()

log.Println(urlvalue.String())

app.Get("/test", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    return GetProject(c)
})
req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", urlvalue.String(), nil)
req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %v", jwt))

r, err := app.Test(req)

log.Println("Request : ", req)

log.Println(r)

assert.Nil(t, err, "There is error")

body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)

log.Println(string(body))

//err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data)
assert.NotNil(t, req, "No value passed ")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.